# Returning List of sub elements when extending a interface

Tags: java, generics, overloading, generic-list

I'm developing a library and i have a faced an issue when overriding the return type as a List of sub elements.

Initially its looked like this,

```
    Class Student {
    }

    public interface A {
        public Student isCurrentStudent(String name);
        public List<Student> getStudentList();
    }

    public interface B extends A {
        public List<Student> getColleges();
        public Student getBestFriend();
    }
```

Then i wanted to introduce SeniorStudent class and APIs for access SeniourStudent, so i came up with follows,

```
Class SeniorStudent extends Student{
}

public interface C extends A {
    public SeniorStudent isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<SeniorStudent> getStudentList();
    public void addStudent(Attributes s);
}

public interface D extends B,C {
    public List<SeniorStudent> getColleges();
    public Student getBestFriend();
}
```

Problem starts with interface C and D. Since java supports for covariant return types, first method of C doesn't give an error. But when the return type is "List", it make's the trouble. So I have changed above interfaces to use generics.

```
public interface A <T extends Student> {
    public Student isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<T> getStudentList();
}

public interface B<T extends Student> extends A<T> {
    public List<T> getColleges();
    public Student getBestFriend();
}

public interface C extends A<SeniorStudent> {
    public SeniorStudent isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<SeniorStudent> getStudentList();
    public void addStudent(Attributes s);
}

public interface D extends B<SeniorStudent>,C {
    public List<SeniorStudent> getColleges();
    public SeniorStudent getBestFriend();
}
```

I believe this design can be improved, such that implementor of class B can be restricted to use Student class only.

What ultimately I wanted to have is, to provide clean API which can be used like this,

```
B bObject = getBObject();
List<Student> studentList = bObject.getColleges();

D dObject = getDObject();
List<SeniourStudent> seniorStudentList = dObject.getColleges();
```

The whole problem would be solved if there is a way to override the return type when it is a List of sub elements.

Since my actual code is much larger, I have used simple example here to describe the problem. Hope its clear enough.

---

**EDIT**

Introducing a BS super type for B would solve the problem. But is it the cleaner way?

[image: class diagram when introducing SB]

```
public interface A <T extends Student> {
    public Student isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<T> getStudentList();
}

public interface BS<T extends Student> extends A<T> {
    public List<T> getColleges();
    public Student getBestFriend();
}

public interface B extends BS<Student> {
    public List<Student> getColleges();
    public Student getBestFriend();
}

public interface C extends A<SeniorStudent> {
    public SeniorStudent isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<SeniorStudent> getStudentList();
    public void addStudent(Attributes s);
}

public interface D extends BS<SeniorStudent>,C {
    public List<SeniorStudent> getColleges();
    public SeniorStudent getBestFriend();
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your base interfaces (A and B) can return List<? super Student>

Comment: You probably meant `List<? extends Student>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Plínio Pantaleão said (or actually, *wanted* to say) in the comment, you can define the interface to return a `List<? extends Student>`

```
import java.util.List;

class Attributes {}
class Student { }

interface A {
    Student isCurrentStudent(String name);
    List<? extends Student> getStudentList();
}

interface B extends A {
    List<? extends Student> getColleges();
}


class SeniorStudent extends Student{ }

interface C extends A {

    @Override
    SeniorStudent isCurrentStudent(String name);

    @Override
    List<SeniorStudent> getStudentList();

    void addStudent(Attributes s);
}

interface D extends B,C {
    @Override
    List<SeniorStudent> getColleges();
}
public class CovariantList
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B b = null;
        List<? extends Student> collegesB = b.getColleges();

        D d = null;
        List<SeniorStudent> collegesD = d.getColleges();
    }
}
```

If you only know the most "basic" interface (B, in this case) you can only obtain a `List<? extends Student>`. If you know the particular type (as in D), you can obtain the covariant type `List<SeniorStudent>`.

---

**EDIT** Update based on the comments and the edited question:

The requirement that the API may be used as in the edited section of the main question could probably be achieved with something like this:

```
import java.util.List;

public class StudentsReturnTypesTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B bObject = getBObject();
        List<Student> studentList = bObject.getColleges();

        D dObject = getDObject();
        List<SeniorStudent> seniorStudentList = dObject.getColleges();        
    }

    private static D getDObject() { return null; }
    private static B getBObject() { return null; }
}

interface A<T extends Student> {
    public Student isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<T> getStudentList();
}

interface AS extends A<Student> { }

interface B extends AS {
    public List<Student> getColleges();
}

interface C extends A<SeniorStudent> {
    public SeniorStudent isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<SeniorStudent> getStudentList();
    public void addStudent(Attributes s);
}

interface D extends C /* B Not possible, see below */  {
    public List<SeniorStudent> getColleges();
}

interface Attributes {}
interface Student {}
interface SeniorStudent extends Student {}
```

**However** in one of the comments, you mentioned

*"For the interface D I wanted to inherit methods from B too"*

This will be difficult. You basically have the problem that the method `getColleagues()` will then be inherited with different return types: Once with `List<Student>` and once with `List<SeniorStudent>`. It's simply not type-safe to do this.

At the moment, the only method that is defined in interface B is `getColleagues()`. And since this method (with a different return type) is already inherited from interface C, I assume that the intention to "...*inherit methods from B too*" referred to methods that are currently not contained in the example code that you posted.

A solution for this could possibly be to extract that the "methods from B" into a dedicated interface. The key point here is to avoid inheriting a method *twice* with different return types. This could possibly be achieved like in this example, where the respective methods are summarized in an interface with the beautiful name `AdditionalMethodsThatHaveBeenInB` ...

```
import java.util.List;

public class StudentsReturnTypesTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B bObject = getBObject();
        List<Student> studentList = bObject.getColleges();
        bObject.methodThatWasInB();

        D dObject = getDObject();
        List<SeniorStudent> seniorStudentList = dObject.getColleges();
        dObject.methodThatWasInB();
    }

    private static D getDObject() { return null; }
    private static B getBObject() { return null; }
}

interface A<T extends Student> {
    public Student isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<T> getStudentList();
}

interface AS extends A<Student> { }

interface B extends AS, AdditionalMethodsThatHaveBeenInB {
    public List<Student> getColleges();
}

interface AdditionalMethodsThatHaveBeenInB {
    void methodThatWasInB();
}

interface C extends A<SeniorStudent> {
    public SeniorStudent isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<SeniorStudent> getStudentList();
    public void addStudent(Attributes s);
}

interface D extends C, AdditionalMethodsThatHaveBeenInB {
    public List<SeniorStudent> getColleges();
}

interface Attributes {}
interface Student {}
interface SeniorStudent extends Student {}
```

Of course, it's hard to tell whether this is also possible in your **real** code, but maybe a similar approach is applicable there.

Comment: In fact i'm doing the same already, isn't it? I use, public List<T> getColleges(); which is forced to define type T when creating the object. I have done that way because i have some more methods which had to return List of Student or SeniourStudent (depending on B or D) and also wanted to all these methods return only a one Type which defines when creating the object.

Comment: And i have updated the question with expected behavior needed to achieve. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @DarRay I updated the answer with an **EDIT**, but it might be tricky due to a method being inherited with different return types...

Comment: Yes, there are other methods which inherited to D from B. I have edited question by adding "public SeniorStudent getBestFriend();" to express such methods. What my current design is somewhat similar to your answer and also align with the @RohitJain also said. Basically what i have done is introduced a new interface "BSuper" which use generics for the methods conflicting and extend B and D from B super separately making genrics types to fixed.

Comment: Updated the question with an **EDIT**

Comment: @DarRay Apart from details (e.g. getBestFriend not necessary in B, because inherited from BS), this seems feasible. But it's hard to say whether this is the most approriate (or "cleanest") solution for the **real** application case. I tried to imagine what these interfaces could represent. Namely, whether the names A,B,C.. could sensibly be replaced by names like "Course" (with Studends) and "AdvancedCourse" (with SeniorStudents), but did not figure out how to map this to a "real world" example.

Comment: @DarRay So I think that the suggested solution (with BS) is "technically valid". But nobody can say whether it appropriately models your particular data domain. (IMHO, to some extent, this also depends on which of these interfaces are intended to be `public` and which ones are package-private, but for now, this may still be just a detail...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit of confused what you're exactly trying to do. But I guess, your problem can be solved by not making interface `C` and `D` generic. You can have your interfaces like so:

```
interface A<T extends Student> {
    public T isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<T> getStudentList();
}

interface B<T extends Student> extends A<T> {
    public List<T> getColleges();
}

interface C extends B<Student> {
    public Student isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<Student> getStudentList();
    public List<Student> getColleges();
}

interface D extends B<SeniorStudent> {
    public SeniorStudent isCurrentStudent(String name);
    public List<SeniorStudent> getStudentList();
    public List<SeniorStudent> getColleges();
}
```

And then, make your class implement interface `C` and `D`, respectively for `Student` and `SeniorStudent`. This is the only way I can think of the top of my head. See if you can get along with this, else we can try to further improvise on this.

Comment: For the interface D I wanted to inherit methods from B too. Sorry  may not clear the question.

Comment: I was referring the question. As per the question, its D and B. According to your answer its D and C.

Comment: As you can see, i'm overriding getColleges() method and B(wrt qustion or C wrt answer) contains more methods which doesnt need to be override.

Comment: @DarRay So you want the interface `C` in my answer not to have `getColleges()` method? I'm still not clear exactly what you want. And I cannot connect how `C` in my answer resembles `B` in the question.

Comment: I was bit confused with your answer previously but if i understood correctly, if i introduce a child class (lets say childB) for the B (wrt question) it will match with your answer. So instead of implementing B and D, I should implement childB and D. I did thought this way, but cant we have much clear design?